# How to delete Selected row in Inline Jqgrid?

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

I want to delete selected row in inline jqgrid.I have try some code but using that all rows are deleted.Please suggest some solution on that.

```
colNames: ['Actions','','Product Code','Product Name'],
        colModel: [
              {label: "Edit Actions",
                  name: "actions",
                  width: 100,
                  formatter: "actions",
                  formatoptions: {
                      keys: true,
                      editOptions: {},
                      addOptions: {},
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you have problem with **filling** the data in the grid. I guess that all rows have **the same** `id` value. Deleting selected row will delete the row with id of selected row. If all rows have the same id then all the rows will be deleted.

Comment: Hi @Oleg I have check but all row are with different Ids e.g id={jqg1,jqg2,jgq3}....

Comment: Are you using **multiselect** mode? Can you please show your full jqGrid setup or prepare a example? Which version of jqGrid is used?

Comment: @Anuja: Which **version** of jqGrid you use and from which **fork** of jqGrid? Could you describe **how you fill jqGrid with the data**? The ids like id={jqg1,jqg2,jgq3} shows that you still have some problem with filling of data. Do you want don't display some row or to **delete** it from the corresponding server source of the data? Do you use paging or sorting the data? If you change the sort order or goes to another page then ids jqg1,jqg2,jgq3 will be typically regenerated. In most scenarios *editing* (or deleting) the data has sense only in you use unique id in every row of data.